# Proper usage of string.Format to format an EVAL

Tags: asp.net, string-formatting

I've got a (probably) simple question, just can't seem to work this out.  I've got a repeater and I want to show tracks on a CD.  My code looks like this:

```
<td><%(string.Format("{0:00}", #EVAL("TrackNo")) %>: <%#Eval("SongName") %></td>
```

Everything was working perfect before I started putzing with the format piece, I want the tracks to line up like:

```
01
02
...
09
10
```

instead of

```
1
2
...
9
10
```

What am I doing wrong?  The field *TrackNo* is an INT, so I read that it might need to be converted to an int first?

Comment: I don't think formatting will work, instead just convert to a string and prepend with a leading zero if the original int was less than 10

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work;

```
<%# string.Format("{0:00}", (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TrackNo"))) %>
```

or

```
<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TrackNo"))).ToString("00") %>
```

Comment: Didn't like either of them, got a "Specific cast not valid" error.